# Как передать данные с MySQL в JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Я по примеру создал карту http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KDHfh. Но мне данные необходимо брать из БД (MySQL) а не вписывать в файл вручную. Я создал index.php Файл в котором создал подключение к БД и сделал тестовый вывод данных:

```
введите сюда код
$query = "SELECT * FROM `map`";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "Region: ".$row['region_name']."<br>\n";
echo "Code of region: ".$row['region_code']."<br>\n";
echo "Value: ".$row['value']."<br><hr>\n";
}
```

Вот теперь мне надо эти переменные связать с JavaScript (map.js) Там есть следующие строчки, которые влияют на цвет карты и название регионов:

```
введите сюда код
var regions=[
{
    "region_name": "region-1",
    "region_code": "id_x5F_1",
    "value": "10"
}
];
```

Comment: ajax https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Подгрузите JSON через Ajax так будет по приятней

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM map";
$pdo_result = $conn->query($sql);
die(json_encode($pdo_result , JSON_UNISCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Далее в js(map.js) подгрузить объект через ajax(я обычно юзаю JQ)

```
var regions;
$.ajax({
    url:'/result.php',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        regions = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Я использую PDO, обычного мускула в PHP 7 потому что нет

Answer (score 0):

В *index.php* инициализируйте ваш массив точек:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `map`";
$res = mysql_query($query);
echo '<script>
    var regions=[';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '{"region_name": "'.$row['region_name'].'",';
    echo '"region_code": "'.$row['region_code'].'",';
    echo '"value": "'.$row['value'].'"},';
}
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: Инициализировал, а в map.js нужно тогда вывести переменную "regions"?

Comment: Переменную которую использует map.js вы должны инициализировать перед его выполнением. У Вас в примере была переменная `regions` я ее и использовал. Да либо используйте ее либо пере назовите на свой лад.

Comment: В map.js - к переменной присвоены постоянные значения, а не из БД. что необходимо вписать в map.js вместо вписанных значений?

Comment: Закоментируйте переменную в map.js.

Comment: Хм... тогда ошитбка... В данный момент основные данные выводятся с файла map.js. И согласно кода региона - происходит раскраска svg областей и назначение соответствующих данных. Но эти данные вручную прописаны в map.js. Файл index.php является не более чем подключение к БД! вывод, о котором вы писали выше - наглядный пример для меня, чтобы я понял что бд и пхп работают.

Comment: а теперь я думаю, как реализовать выборку данных из бд в переменные, которые прописаны в файле map.js вместо  `region-1, id_x5F_1 и значения 10`

Comment: Извините за выражение, но Вы "втираете какую-то дичь", либо не понимаете как что работает. Попросите помощи у книги по web разработки.